# Gnuplot: How can I fit a range of points (out of the entire data) to a function?

Tags: interpolation, regression, curve-fitting, gnuplot

I have a set of data obtained for the I-V characteristics of an LED.

```
0.005  -0.004
0.053  -0.003
0.101  -0.003
0.153  -0.002
0.201  -0.002
0.252  -0.002
0.303  -0.004
0.354  -0.004
0.403  -0.004
0.454  -0.003
0.503  -0.003
0.554  -0.003
0.603  -0.003
0.654  -0.003
0.702  -0.003
0.753  -0.002
0.802  -0.002
0.853  -0.002
0.902  -0.002
0.953  -0.001
1.002  -0.002
1.050  -0.001
1.104  -0.004
1.153  -0.004
1.204  -0.004
1.253  -0.004
1.304  -0.004
1.353  -0.003
1.404  -0.003
1.452  -0.003
1.503  -0.003
1.552  -0.002
1.603  -0.003
1.652  -0.002
1.703  -0.002
1.752  -0.002
1.803  -0.002
1.851  -0.001
1.903  -0.002
1.954  -0.004
2.005  -0.004
2.054  -0.004
2.102  -0.003
2.153  -0.003
2.202  -0.003
2.253  -0.003
2.301  -0.002
2.352  -0.001
2.398  0.001
2.442  0.008
2.475  0.024
2.501  0.050
2.519  0.081
2.533  0.118
2.544  0.156
2.552  0.199
2.560  0.240
2.567  0.284
2.573  0.327
2.578  0.373
2.583  0.417
2.587  0.462
2.591  0.509
2.595  0.554
2.599  0.601
2.602  0.647
2.606  0.694
2.609  0.740
2.611  0.789
2.615  0.835
2.617  0.883
2.620  0.929
2.622  0.978
2.625  1.025
2.627  1.073
2.630  1.120
2.632  1.169
2.635  1.215
2.637  1.264
2.639  1.311
2.641  1.358
2.643  1.407
2.645  1.454
2.648  1.503
2.649  1.550
2.652  1.599
2.653  1.646
2.655  1.696
2.657  1.743
2.658  1.792
2.660  1.839
2.662  1.889
2.664  1.936
2.666  1.985
2.667  2.033
2.668  2.082
2.670  2.129
2.672  2.179
2.674  2.226
2.675  2.276
2.676  2.324
```

How do I fit only a range of values out of this data to a linear function? I am able to achieve this by saving the required range of data as a separate file `linear-07.txt` and then fitting this set of values to the function f(x).

```
set term svg
set output 'blue.svg'
set term svg
set output 'blue.svg'

f(x) = a*x + b
fit f(x) 'linear-07.txt' via a,b

plot[][-1:3] '07-B.txt' pt 7, f(x)
```

However this seems to be exhausting. Is there an alternate method to this?

Also, How do I obtain the x-value (of the fit function) corresponding to f(x)=0?

Comment: `fit` supports ranges like `plot`, e.g. `fit [0:0.5] f(x) 'file' via a,b`. The `a` and `b` values are saved as `a` and `b`, try printing them after fitting: `print a, b`

Comment: Thank you, giving the range for fit solved my first problem. For the second part, are you suggesting that I use `print -b/a` to obtain the required value?

Comment: I misunderstood your last question, but yes that works :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Thor](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users/31611/thor), I figured out the solutions to my questions.

As he pointed out, the range of the function can be specified in the `fit` command. In the above data set, the linear region starts from `x=2.63`.

```
set term svg
set output 'blue.svg'
set term svg
set output 'blue.svg'

f(x) = a*x + b
fit[2.63:] f(x) '07-B.txt' via a,b

plot[][-1:3] '07-B.txt' pt 7, f(x)
```

Now, to obtain the $x$ corresponding to $f(x)=0$, since $f(x) = ax + b$, the required $x$ is given by 
$$x = -\dfrac{b}{a}$$

Hence, adding the line

```
print -b/a
```

gives the required value of `x`.